# Generate a Real list from a Int list in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

Hello every body im training some SMLs and im creating a code to get deviation of a int list . in the process of it , i need to get a Real list out of some numbers in a int list , which it doesnt let me get them. heres my code :

```
fun mean [] = 0.0
  | mean (first::rest) = 
      let 
        fun sum [] = 0
          | sum (x::xs) = x + sum xs
          
        fun counter [] = 0
          | counter (y::ys) = 1 + counter ys       
      in 
        Real.fromInt (sum (first::rest)) / Real.fromInt (counter (first::rest))
      end;

fun deviation [] = 0.0
  | deviation (first::rest) = 
      let 
        fun diff (x::xs) = (x - mean (x::xs)) :: diff xs;
      in
        diff (first , first::rest) + deviation rest
      end;
```

the problem is here :

```
fun diff (x::xs) = (x - mean (x::xs) ) :: diff xs;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff` is a recursive function, but the base case is never defined. When you try to run `diff` on an empty list, you will get a pattern match error.

You also define `diff` to accept a list, but you call it with a tuple.

You define `diff` as returning a list, given that you are using `::`, but then you use addition on the result of that function, which will not work.

### Improving `mean`

You can simplify your `sum` and `counter` functions with folds.

```
fun mean [] = 0.0
  | mean lst = 
      let 
        val sum = foldl op+ 0 lst
        val counter = foldl (fn (_, c) => c + 1) 0 lst      
      in 
        Real.fromInt sum / Real.fromInt counter
      end;
```

But this requires iterating the entire list twice, when both pieces of information can be ascertained at the same time.

```
fun sumLen(lst) =
  foldl (fn (x, (sum, len)) => (sum+x, len+1)) (0, 0) lst
```

`mean` can now be implemented as:

```
fun mean(lst) =
  let 
    val (sum, len) = sumLen(lst)
  in
    Real.fromInt sum / Real.fromInt len
  end
```

### Deviation

To get the differences from the mean for a list, you need only use `map`.

```
fun diffs(lst) =
  let 
    val m = mean(lst)
  in
    map (fn x => Real.fromInt x - m) lst
  end
```

Consider evaluating the following.

```
diffs [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The result is:

```
[~3.5, ~2.5, ~1.5, ~0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
```

From there you can use `map` and `Math.pow` to square those differences, `foldl` to sum them, divide by the length of the list, and then `Math.sqrt` to get the standard deviation.